Rebuilding of bounded linear operator between Banach spaces
It is possible to rebuild a bounded linear operator between Banach spaces knowing the image only through the dual elements?
Maybe we need some other hypothesis but the statement could be something like:
Let $Y, X$ be Banach spaces on $\mathbb{K}\in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$, let $X$ be endowed with weak topology, $\sigma(X, X^*)$, let $f_{x^*} \in \mathcal{L}(Y, \mathbb{K})$ (i.e linear and bounded) $\forall x^* \in X^*$, Then $\exists !$ (or $\exists$) $f\in \mathcal{L}(Y, X)$ such that $f_{x^*}=x^* \circ f, \forall x^* \in X^*$


You need two additional hypotheses at least for the result to be true: 1) $f_{x*}$ has to be linear in $x^$ 2) $f_{x^}$ has to be equicontinuous (provided $x^\in B_{X^}$)

You have uniqueness of $f$ (when it exists) for free since $X^*$ separates the points of $X$ (I'm only addressing the "(or $\exists$)").

just some thoughts: maybe you could assume reflexiveness and use some Banach-Steinhaus argument in order to obtain elements $f(y)\in X$ satisfying what you want (before even talking about continuity). [Simliar to the argument that in a reflexive Banach space for a sequence $x_n$ we already get weak convergence (i.e. some $x\in X$ s.t. $\lambda(x_n)\to\lambda(x)$) if we just assume convergence of the sequnces $\lambda(x_n)$ for every $\lambda \in X'$]  However, I haven't given it any further thought yet.

With the proper assumptions added, your conditions should uniquely define an operator $f \in L(Y,X^{**})$. Without further assumptions, this is all you can say. If X is reflexive, your statement is probably true (after adding the assumptions mentioned by @Pelota)

Assume in addition that $f_{x*}$ is linear in $x^*$ and that the family
$\{f_{x^*}\}_{x^*\in B_{X^*}}$ is equicontinuous.
First, notice that given any $y$ in $Y$, there exists at most one $x$ such that
$$\forall x^*\  f_{x^*}(y)=x^*(x),$$
since linear functionals separate points. Assume for the moment that
such an $x(y)$ exists for any $y$: it follows that we can define $f(y)=x(y)$.
This operator is clearly linear and we claim it is norm continuous as well: indeed, by the equicontinuity hypothesis it follows that $f$ sends bounded sets to weakly bounded (hence bounded) sets.
Thus the main issue is the existence of $x(y)$. First, we argue that if $X$ is reflexive, we can construct $x(y)$:
for any $x^*\in B_{X^*}$, define
$$K_{x^*,y}:=\left\{x: x^*\left(x\right)=f_{x^*}(y); \|x\|\le 2(|f_{x^*}(y)|+1)\right\}.$$
It is easy to see that
$$x\in \bigcap_{x^*\in B_{X^*}} K_{x^*, y}\Rightarrow x=x(y),$$
hence it suffices to prove that the intersection is nonempty. Since $K_{x^*,y}\subset B_{C}$ for some $C$ large enough depending on $y$ (by equicontinuity), it suffices to prove that the family $K_{x^*,y}$ has the finite intersection property which easily follows from reflexivity and Hahn-Banach.
This same argument allows us to define $x(y)$ more generally (i.e., without the reflexivity hypothesis) as an element of $X^{**}$. Indeed, for nonreflexive spaces we can prove the existence of $f\in \mathcal L(Y,X^{**})$. Unfortunately, nothing more can be said, as the following example shows:
Assume $X$ is not reflexive and let $f:Y\to X^{**}$ be a linear continuous map that takes some values in $X^{**}\setminus X$. Define
$f_{x^*}(y):=f(y)(x^*).$
Then it is clear that this family satisfies all the hypotheses, $f\in \mathcal L(Y,X)$ does not exist (for an explicit example, take $Y=\ell_\infty, X=c_0$
and $f_{x^*}=x^*$).

Thank you, very clear answer!

Sorry, can i ask you some clarification about why Is sufficient to show the finite intersection property to conclude that the uncountable intersection Is non empty?

@ManuelBonanno the family of sets $K_{x;*,y}$ is made of compact sets (in the weak topology) and it is well known that a family of compact sets has nonempty intersection if and only if it has the FIP
